# ATtiny85 Yikes Error While Burning Bootloader

Tags: microcontroller, avr, surface-mount, arduino-uno, attiny85

I'm using an Elegoo uno to burn the ArduinoISP example code on to an [ATtiny85 SMD](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2011170235_Microchip-Tech-ATTINY85-20SU_C89852.pdf). I wired the board according to the "#define USE_OLD_STYLE_WIRING" using pins 13/12/11/10. The wiring diagram for the circuit board is [here](https://i.gyazo.com/4bb7156a0d238332f96f28d8cff8a295.png). I first upload the sketch as "Board -> Arduino Uno" and it uploads successfully. I then click burn bootloader, using the following settings [here](https://i.gyazo.com/a0d584bb0034dcce764ee5627ac0636d.png). I get the error listed below after trying to upload to the ATtiny85. Any ideas?

https://gist.github.com/gmanc2/8e0b354d75c80d648f526b03fd6f8cf1

code: https://gist.github.com/gmanc2/683803105034c2c1ac1393d1f6b26cef

I have run the burn code only with the 1mhz internal crystal and 8mhz internal crystal selected. I if it is the case I accidentally selected an external crystal source, I don't have any 1-8 mhz external crystals. This error happened on my second attempt to burn to the board. Are there any other options besides buying a crystal? I'm fairly certain my wiring is correct. I have an oscilloscope is there any way I can verify the clock speed?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: You could probably run a fast timer output of the Arduino and inject it as a clock, do some research someone has probably written it up

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've looked around and haven't found anything yet and there's not a guide that I've been able to find please let me know if you have one!

Comment: Setting the fuse bits wrong to expect external clock is extremely common problem, and people have asked solutions to this on the internet as long as AVRs have existed, so about 20 years now. It can be solved by any means you have available to give the chip a clock signal of suitable speed.